# Recover corrupted Ubuntu partition

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, partition-recovery

So I have a laptop dual-booting Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04, and my Ubuntu partition ran out of space. I shrank the only partition I could to make more room for Ubuntu, but the unallocated space came before the partition and I couldn't extend into it. I tried switching the partition and unallocated space, but quickly realized that my computer no longer knew where Ubuntu was. I tried moving it back, but that didn't fix it. I did back up my filesystem beforehand, but like a noob I forgot to copy the backups somewhere else. All my important files are already backed up, but I'd prefer to be able to easily restore all my system settings when I reinstall Ubuntu. Is there a way I can recover my backup files from my Ubuntu partition?

**EDIT**
Can I recover my data by cloning the partition into the unallocated space? Since I only moved the partition, presumably nothing inside it is actually corrupted, so in theory cloning it would produce an exact copy and my computer would know where it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the partition you moved contained /boot? Try this question:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/299886/partitions-is-it-safe-to-move-partition-containing-boot